# Any tips on fixing this horrendous security flaw in SCORM 1.2? Are we doing it right?

Tags: javascript, scorm, scorm1.2

The way that scorm 1.2 is supposed to be setup, is you have your RTE page, and then two iframes, which are your API and then your actual Lesson (SCO)

In the API there are javascript functions that get / set data into the database.

However, you could do something super simple like -> right click, inspect element, edit HTML text

Then just add:

```
<button onclick="window.parent.parent.frames[0].LMSSetValue('GARBAGE','DATA')">Click me to insert garbage into the DB</button>
```

Then obviously it adds a button that calls a MANDATORY SCORM FUNCTION that needs to be accessible by the SCO, and you click the button 100 times and suddenly the database gets a bunch of junk.

Likewise you could make the button call a function you create, and do it 10,000 or once every 1millisecond, etc. etc....

Or even you could make it do LMSGetValue('valuename') and then start retrieving records from the database!!!!!

---

Is this not a huge security flaw? Are we doing something wrong? Are there ways to prevent something like this from happening?

I read that some programmer created a chrome extension that when clicked once, inserted all the necessary information to auto complete any SCORM 1.2 lesson.... AKA they just called the functions ("LMSSetValue") with values like "lesson_status = complete"

So does this not mean that SCORM 1.2 is not very secure at all?

Comment: Is this a question or a rant?

Comment: This is a question. Did you not see me asking actual questions? "Are there ways to prevent something like this from happening?"

Comment: If `LMSGetValue('valuename')` reveals data that is supposed to be private, then the browser client code is the least of your worries, because the server side itself is unsecured.

Comment: @WillCain Hi, Will. Thanks for your input, the SCO (one of the IFRAMES) needs to be able to retrieve data from LMSGetValue('valuename') but I don't see any checks that prevent anything from calling this function.

Comment: This is excellent fuel for my general ire towards enterprise software. +1, I hope you get an answer, I've been looking at the source of a site using SCORM for fun and it would be very interesting seeing what the consensus is on whether this is an actual security flaw.

Comment: Cool; it sounds like from tempshrimp's last comment that there is no particularly privileged data revealed by `LMSGetValue('valuename')`, so I wouldn't consider that a security concern in its own right. (From Klaycon's detailed answer it seems the security concerns with SCORM go much deeper anyway.)

Comment: Generally Klaycon's answer is correct, but it should be cleared up that the DOS and general security aspect of the comments made isn't really at play. You can't get "arbitrary" records from a "database". The whole of the SCORM RTE is JS based intended for a client, there is no requirement for "database" access, so you can implement it with local comms to data already provided. The most prevalent SCORM player(s) are implemented in this way, so you'd be effectively getting the exact same value every millisecond and you'd be DOS'ing your own local machine *NOT* whatever the player connects to.

Answer (score 4):

The official [SCORM blog](https://scorm.com/blog/scorm-security-some-perspective/)  has a post about this very issue that you'll probably find interesting. I've quoted some relevant bits below.

> The crux of the issue is that since SCORM communication uses JavaScript in a web browser it is inherently insecure and can be spoofed by any semi-competent web developer who knows a little bit about SCORM. This means that somebody who knows what they are doing can trick an LMS into thinking that a course was completed using some rather simple scripting. The fact that SCORM makes it easy for content to communicate with the LMS also makes it easy for a hacker to maliciously communicate with that LMS.
>
> This issue is not new. It has been widely known for quite some time. [...]
>
> [...] I fully agree that SCORM should be made more secure, please don’t doubt that. This post is designed to put security in perspective, calm the panic and ensure that whatever solution we adopt moving forward doesn’t sacrifice other important principles in the name of security.
>
> [...]
>
> Let’s pretend for a moment that we implement Fort Knox level security into SCORM. Assume that there is absolutely no way for a malicious user to alter the communications between the content and the LMS. Will we then have achieved secure online training? Will we then have something that is good enough for “high stakes”? Not really. Not in any of the three areas required for secure online training.
>
> Most fundamentally, how are we sure that “the identified learner” is the one actually taking the online training? How do we close the security vulnerability of “offering to buy my buddy a pizza” if he will click through my training while he is doing his anyway?
>
> How do we ensure that the learner is really “experiencing the intended delivery of instructional content” and not just watching YouTube videos while mindlessly clicking through the content?
>
> How do we ensure that the learner has really “retained the knowledge” and isn’t just looking up the answers on Google or asking his buddy in the next cubicle what the test answers are? Online training is an open book test.

Looks like they acknowledge the model has zero security and have decided to make no attempt to fix it. The blog post is old but not as old as SCORM 1.2.

In summary, you're absolutely doing it right. Keep it up! I'm not sure that there's any way to fix this security issue given the requirements of using the system.

Comment: SCORM is completely exposing API (SCORM 1.2) and API_1484_11 (SCORM 2004).  This is why I strongly advocate LMS systems monitor times the students are viewing a SCO outside of SCORM session time.  Cheaters attempt to use bookmarklets to set there scores, or attempt to directly work with the API's via the browser console, or how things were portrayed above.  I would note, if the Runtime API is done correctly 'junk' shouldn't be making it in.  This is the sole purpose of the Runtime API - enforcement of the spec.